# Condensing of $f(x)=\sec(\frac{\pi}{4}x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The function $f(x)=\sec(\frac{\pi}{4}x)$ is undefined every time $\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}x)$is equal to $0$.

Therefore, I set cosine equal to zero, and the solutions I got were:

> $x=2+8k$                   and     $x=6+8k$
>   $$k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

I decided to condense the solutions into one, and got:

> $$x=2+4k$$
>   $$k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Is the way I condensed it correct? If it is, is this how you would define where $\sec(\frac{\pi}{4}x)$ is continuous?

> $$x\in\mathbb{R}\lvert x\ne2+4k\lvert k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rigorously show that condensation,
you need to show that
$\{8k+2\}\cup\{8k+6\}
=\{4k+2\}
$.

Here's how I would do
that seemingly obvious proof:

If $n = 8k+2$,
then
$n = 4(2k)+2$,
so
$n \in \{4k+2\}
$,
so
$\{8k+2\} \subset \{4k+2\}
$.

Similarly,
if $n = 8k+6$,
then
$n 
= 4(2k)+4+2
= 4(2k+1)+2
$,
so
$n \in \{4k+2\}
$,
so
$\{8k+6\} \subset \{4k+2\}
$.

Therefore
$\{8k+2\}\cup\{8k+6\} \subset \{4k+2\}
$.

To go the other way,
if $n = 4k+2$,
then $k$ is either even or odd,
so either $k = 2j$ 
or $k = 2j+1$
for some $j$.

In the first case,
$n = 4k+2
=4(2j)+2
=8j+2
$
so $n \in \{8k+2\}
$.

In the second case,
$n = 4k+2
=4(2j+1)+2
=8j+6
$
so $n \in \{8k+6\}
$.

Therefore
$\{4k+2\}
\subset \{8k+2\}\cup\{8k+6\}
$.

As to where
$\sec(\frac{\pi}{4}x)$ 
is continuous,
be sure that you include
negative $k$.

Comment: Thanks, I was really confused on how to show work for it.  My brain was just like that is the condensed form, and I had no idea how I arrived at the answer.